# Чтение изображения в сервлет

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet

Задание заключается в выводе на экран картинок по заданной тематике на экран с помощью сервлетов. Проблема в том, что я не могу получить картинку. Получаю исключение "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!".
Код получения картинок:

```
BufferedImage ISport = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("resources/run.jpg"));
BufferedImage IAnimal = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("resources/olen.jpg"));
BufferedImage INature = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("lake.jpg"));
BufferedImage IWater = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("sea.jpg"));
BufferedImage ICelebrities = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("willSmith.jpg"));
```

Находил еще вариант

```
BufferedImage ISport = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/run.jpg"));
```

Но получаю сообщение о том, что файл не может быть считан.

Также прикрепляю весь код сервлета. Сервлет развертывается на локальном сервере Tomcat.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@WebServlet("/hello")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        BufferedImage ISport = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("resources/run.jpg"));
        BufferedImage IAnimal = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("resources/olen.jpg"));
        BufferedImage INature = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("lake.jpg"));
        BufferedImage IWater = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("sea.jpg"));
        BufferedImage ICelebrities = ImageIO.read( MainServlet.class.getResource("willSmith.jpg"));

        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

            pw.println("<p><h2>Enter your number:</h2></p>");
            pw.println("<p><h4>1 - sport</h4></p>");
            pw.println("<p><h4>2 - animals</h4></p>");
            pw.println("<p><h4>3 - nature</h4></p>");
            pw.println("<p><h4>4 - celebrities</h4></p>");
            pw.println("<p><h4>5 - water (sea/ocean/lake etc)</h4></p>");

            pw.close();

            String id = req.getParameter("id");

            switch (id){
                case "1": ImageIO.write(ISport, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream());break;
                case "2": ImageIO.write(IAnimal, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream());break;
                case "3": ImageIO.write(INature, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream());break;
                case "4": ImageIO.write(ICelebrities, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream());break;
                case "5": ImageIO.write(IWater, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream()); break;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я может быть чот уже не понимаю в сервлетах, вебе и всём таком. Но лично мне видится следующее. Вы пишите:

```
resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");
...
PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
pw.println("<p><h2>Enter your number:</h2></p>");
...
```

Но уже это выглядит противоречиво. Вы наобещали в ответе отправить картинку и тут же в ответ кладёте строки.

Затем вы пытаетесь туда ещё как-то изображения доложить:

```
ImageIO.write(ISport, "JPG", resp.getOutputStream());break;
```

У меня просто дикие сомнения, что это должно так работать. Может быть стоит и пообещать и положить в ответ строки. Изображения хранить на сервере, а в строках вкладывать изображение в документ с помощью тега

```
<img src='path/to/image.jpg'/>
```

Во всяком случае раньше веб работал как-то так.